# How do I assign the current cell's address to a Range variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm confused on how to update a Range variable with the current cell. Say I have the following:

```
Dim site_curr_position As Range
Set site_curr_position = Worksheets("newsheet").Range("D14")
Set site_curr_position = Worksheets("newsheet").Range("E14")
Worksheets("newsheet").Range("A4").Select
'Set site_curr_position = ?
```

How do I get the range of that cell where the cursor is now placed?

Comment: In your example, should site_curr_position be Range("A4")?

Comment: In general, you should always try to avoid using `.Activate` and `.Select`.  Relying on those is largely considered bad practice.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1) for why.  To answer your question however, it would simply be `Set site_curr_position = Selection`

Comment: `ActiveCell` gets you the cell that's currently active... but please read the link @tigeravatar posted. FWIW the second assignment is voiding the first.